# What is the best way to make an iframe full screen on mobile only?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iframe that I want to be full screen only on mobile. I'm seeing solutions for showing full screen on all screens, but that isn't what I want.

Here's my code as of now:

```html
<p align="center"><iframe src="LINK" title="iframe" width="900" height="650" frameBorder="0"></p>
</iframe>
```

I should probably use percentages for width and height on desktop, right? But I don't know how to do that AND set a width and height of 100% on mobile devices.

Comment: How do I write media queries that will only made the iframe full screen on mobile, not desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a media query:

```
<iframe class="iframe" src="https://www.google.com/" frameborder="0"></iframe>

.iframe {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .iframe {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/51c4cf447763a01468f7f517518b619f

Answer (score -1):

To cover the entire viewport, you can use:

```
<p align="center">
<iframe src="LINK" title="iframe" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
</p>
```

That will fill the entire page or part you want to fill.

for apply on mobile devices remove the inline style code from iframe tag and use this media query on your css file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  iframe {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px; 
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:999999;
  }
}
```